# See text/content of stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

As per client requirement, our project has a functionality this needs to configure the stored procedure from UI along with user input. After successfully saved the configuration(Its created new procedure in database), I need to display the content(which database **"tables"** are used in it) of the stored procedure on display.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! As posted this question doesn't make a lot of sense. We are not sure what you are trying to do here. Can you try to explain this more clearly?

Comment: You are writing software in some unspecified language and the requirement is that the user can change the stored procedure... or something... and you need to save the procedure and then display it to the user? Are you just trying to get the procedure definition after submitting the `CREATE procedure` statement? [try here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/view-the-definition-of-a-stored-procedure)